# How to move old VC6 project to VS2010 using Daffodil

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-6

I've been interested in [this](http://daffodil.codeplex.com/) project lately.
I have an old legacy project made in VC6, which I hear is a great IDE but doesn't run smoothly on my machine. I also don't know how to work with it. A full blown move to a 2010/12 project is a big time spent so I wonder:

1. Can  someone share some basic information on how to use this tool? I've been searching a lot and couldn't find anything more comprehensive than the site.
2. Which specific old VC6 tools do I need to make sure to have working for Daffodil? (compiler, linker, etc) where are they located on the installed machine?

Comment: You are asking several questions in one, none of which can be easily answered. That makes it a bad fit for a Q&A site, because there is really no A. If you have a current Visual Studio, you could start by getting the Daffodil tool from [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da1f2443-624b-43b7-8480-b092b2962843/).

Comment: I'e narrowed my question to Daffodil usage only. What do you think @Bo Persson

Comment: I actually have no idea. :-) I have moved my VC6 projects to VS2002, 2003, 2005, 2008 and 2010, in turn. Have never needed this tool.

Comment: You can always +1 for the change.

Comment: Just checked, standard VS2010 will still open .dsp files from VS6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build your project in VS 2010:

1. Make sure the VC 6 build tools are installed and working.
2. Make sure VS 2010 and Daffodil are installed and working.
3. Open your VS 6 workspace in VS 2010.
   A. In Explorer, right-click on your VS 6 workspace (*.dsw) file.
   B. Choose Open With -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.
   C. Perform the migration when prompted.
4. Change the Platform Toolset to v60.
   A. Right click on the project(s) and select Properties.
   B. On the General page, set Platform Toolset to v60.
5. Build.

Answer (score 1):

A quick read tells me that the concept of "Daffodil" is to use the VC6 compiler with the VS2010 IDE. Therefore, you wouldn't run VS6 on your machine. You just need the VC6 compiler and linker.

Comment: What about the setup of the project ? Do I need to let it convert to 2010 project? Can you share a link to detailed step by step example?

Comment: @qballer: I just browsed the site you linked to. I just happen to know that the VS2010 IDE can use other toolsets, if those are provided in the right way. Then it's not a big jump to conclude how Daffodil works.

Answer (score 0):

Start by letting Vs2012 migrate the project and see what doesn't work properly. The newer compilers are much better -once you've gone  through the pain of the conversion.

Comment: Migrating VC6 projects hasn't been supported for the last couple of versions. It's 14 years... :-)