# Using legacy toolset from VS2005 in VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, cross-compiling

I ran into the rare situation that I have to use static libraries in a project which were compiled with Visual Studio 2005.
As I do not want to get into trouble at runtime as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744543/can-i-mix-different-visual-c-runtimes-with-a-static-library) or [here](https://siomsystems.com/mixing-visual-studio-versions/),
I think it's reasonable to use the original toolset.  
As far as I have seen, using toolsets down to [VS2008](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/stuck-on-an-older-toolset-version-move-to-visual-studio-2015-without-upgrading-your-toolset/) is straightforward. For VS2005 this seems to be more challenging, only [Daffodil](https://github.com/georgeto/Daffodil) might be an option.  
**Is there any chance to get the toolset v80 (VS2005) into the dropdown menu of VS2019 ?**  
After playing around, I don't know exactly understand how daffodil works or how a feasible approach looks like.

Maybe one could create wrapper-DLLs with a plain C-API and the help of VS2005. Using one IDE with various toolsets feels advantageously to me.

Answer (score 0):

Daffodil works only in earlier versions of Visual Studio 2012/2013/2015.

For using daffodils, check out the related thread: [How to move old VC6 project to VS2010 using Daffodil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775496/how-to-move-old-vc6-project-to-vs2010-using-daffodil).

> To build your project in VS 2010:
>
> Make sure the VC 6 build tools are installed and working. Make sure VS
> 2010 and Daffodil are installed and working. Open your VS 6 workspace
> in VS 2010. A. In Explorer, right-click on your VS 6 workspace (*.dsw)
> file. B. Choose Open With -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. C. Perform
> the migration when prompted. Change the Platform Toolset to v60. A.
> Right click on the project(s) and select Properties. B. On the General
> page, set Platform Toolset to v60. Build.

Comment: Hi, @Ambitions964
Did the answer help you?

Comment: Hello @Minxin Yu - MSFT . The answer does not really help me, as I do not get how to "install" daffodil correctly. Do I have to copy the .props files of Daffodil to the msbuild folder like mentinoned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839098/how-can-i-add-the-platform-toolset-of-visual-studio-2005-into-the-platform-tool) ? Anyway, I wanted to VS2019 and not VS2015. As I could live with VS2015 I'll try to grab one.